# Poor and good conceptual model

Tags: mental-models

I read about the conceptual model in this book: Design of Everyday things.

Could someone told me an another good and bad conceptual model, not the fridge one?

Comment: This isn't a suitable question for a Q&A website. As per the [FAQ] "*You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. "*. Do you have an actual problem that you need a solution to?

Comment: yes I try to understand the conceptual model meaning in practice, this is a problem what I want to solve and is important for me.

Comment: @flatronka In that case, you should have asked for a definition, not examples....although a definition isn't suited for this site either.  Instead, why not rephrase your question to ask specifically what it is you're having understanding about conceptual models?  It might help if you read up on them first: they're also known as mental models: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/mental-models/.  Another common example of a problem with them is ABS brakes vs normal breaks for a car; if people don't understand how the car works, they may brake the wrong way.

Comment: the mental model and the conceptual model is not the same thing

Comment: We can't just list examples, that is not a question that can be answered. Can you [edit] your question so that you are asking a specific and answerable question and if it's suitable for the site we'll be happy to answer it, but it's not clear currently and appears to be a request for some examples of conceptual models (which, if so, isn't appropriate).

Answer (score 3):

Dragging the floppy disc icon to the trash to eject it is a classic twisted mixed up conceptual model.

Comment: hm interesting example

Comment: I've watched people go into a cold sweat the first time they were told to do this " but won't it delete all my files ?!! "

Answer (score 0):

Room Thermostats are the other classic example:

People think that turning up the thermostat increases the flow of heat to the radiators so that a room will warm up quicker if the thermostat is turned up.

This has no effect at all on the speed the room heats up - but does increase the final temperature which the room reaches.